# Selecting from a list of applications using an Apple Remote

Tags: remote-control, mediaplayer, netflix, plex

I have a 2009 Mac Mini running Mavericks that I am planning to use as a media center. There are a few apps that I would like to be able to launch using the Apple Remote (Plex, Netflix via Safari shortcut, etc.)

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[**BetterTouchTool**](http://www.boastr.net) has a section for Apple Remote buttons that can be configured to perform a number of actions:

[image: BTT Apple Remote]